# What is the shortest way to calculate the nth prime?

Tags: c, code-golf, primes

What is the shortest **C code** to "**Calculate the *n*-th prime**"?

Shortest in terms of **significant characters**, i.e. *the number of semicolons, non-whitespace characters, keywords and commas*.

### Input:

Integers *n* from the standard input, separated by new lines. The input will be terminated by EOF.

### Output:

Right after the input *n*, print the *n*-th prime to the standard output separated by new lines.

(You may assume the prime numbers are < 10,000, i.e. *n* < 1,230.)

---

### Test cases:

```
Input:
    1
    2
    4
    8
    32
    999
    42
    5

Output:
    2
    3
    7
    19
    131
    7907
    181
    11
```

---

My attempt :

```
 #define m 10000
 a[m],b[m],x;

 main(i,j){
   for(i=2;i<m;i++)
      {
       if (!a[i])
       for (b[++x]=i,j=2*i;j<m;j+=i)
            a[j]=1;
      }
   for(;~scanf("%d",&i);printf("%d\n",b[i]));
  }
```

For this problem readability is not a concern.A costlier code in terms of time and memory but satisfying the constraint will be considered better here.

Comment: thats what code golf is!!! least number of keystrokes.Helps you understand better, the language you are coding in.

Comment: @nthrgeek, you should also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/

Comment: Can you please explain the input more or give an example? It's not completely clear what exactly you're suppose to do. For example, you say "Each *line* will have many vales of N, each separated by a *new line* such". I think an example of input output would help.

Comment: Must the code be in C? If not, remove the "c" tag.

Comment: I've never been a fan of code-golf on SO, but with language restrictions it is simply intolerable. Not a Real Question. Not even close.

Comment: I think Code-Golf should (unless there is some special exception, which I can not even think of) be language agnostic. And this is not a special exception.

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica: 13 characters

```
Prime@Input[]
```

The [`Prime`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prime.html) function is built-in.

---

As a REPL: **34** characters

```
While[0<(s=Input[]),Print@Prime@s]
```

or, performing exactly 10,000 times, in **29** characters:

```
Print@Prime@Input[]~Do~{1*^4}
```

Answer (score 3):

## C: 104 characters

```
i,t,n;g(){!--n?t=1:g();for(i=++t;1<--i;i=t%i?i:t++);}main(){for(;~scanf("%d",&n);g(),printf("%d\n",t));}
```

(And, of course, it runs in exponential time.)

(BTW, restricting to C is boring. Most `code-golf` here nowadays is `language-agnostic`.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt in Python. I didn't understand what exactly you meant in the input format, but this should take care of all cases. Also, it is horribly slow and takes a few seconds to generate the primes before it is ready to process input. The weird input parsing causes it to slurp in all input at once before starting to produce output so you should input numbers and end the list with an EOF and then get the answers all at once (or redirect input from a file).

```
import sys
p=[2]
for i in xrange(3,105000,2):
    if all(i%x for x in p):
        p.append(i)
print '\n'.join(str(p[int(i)-1]) for i in sys.stdin.read().split())
```

152 Characters (with spaces)

130 Characters (without spaces)

Comment: @ MAk : I am looking for a C solution only.

Comment: Please state so in your question, then.